# Python :Select the rows for the most recent entry from multiple users

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with 3 columns :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'User':['A','A','B','A','C','B','C'],
    'Values':['x','y','z','p','q','r','s'],
    'Date':[14,11,14,12,13,10,14]
})
```

I want to create a new dataframe that will contain the rows corresponding to highest values in the 'Date' columns for each user. For example for the above dataframe I want the desired dataframe to be as follows ( its a jpeg image):

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: There is not `count` column here. Can you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes that there is different maximum values per user in `Values` column:

```
In [10]: def get_max(group):
    ...:     return group[group.Date == group.Date.max()]
    ...: 

In [12]: df.groupby('User').apply(get_max).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[12]: 
   Date User Values
0    14    A      x
1    14    B      z
2    14    C      s
```